# `push_back` to `vector< reference_wrapper<string> >` cause string at index 0 to be empty

Tags: c++, reference-wrapper

I have two classes which is a direct inheritance with no override, so they are basically: `vector<string> list` and `vector< reference_wrapper<string> > filtered`. The idea is I want to store all values into `list` and then fill the `filtered` with selected data from `list`.

Now, when I do `filtered.push_back()` if it has size of 1, the reference at index 0 would return an empty string (length = 0).

```
// concept code
int main() {
    vector<string> list;
    vector< reference_wrapper<string> > filtered;

    string line;
    for (;;) {
        if (!getline(cin, line, '\n').good()) {
            cout << "Bad input! Exiting..." << endl;
            break;
        } else if (line.length() > 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            list.push_back(line);
            //   filtered[0].length() NOT 0 (size() = 1)
            filtered.push_back(list.back());
            //   filtered[0].length() is now 0
        }

        // then print to screen... cout
    }
```

Why does this happen?

---

Here's an example:

```
// cout when size() = 1
[1] Hello world

// cout when size() = 2
[1] 
[2] Hi!

// cout when size() = 3
[1] 
[2] Hi!
[3] My world
```

Comment: Could it be that `line` is the empty string?

Comment: `// filtered[0].length() NOT 0` - Yeah, before you pushed something into it. This premise is based on undefined behavior. How about posting a proper [mcve] to avoid this guessing game?

Comment: @StoryTeller filtered[0].length() is not 0 when the size >= 1...

Comment: @Yola: It is not empty. I have checked it for length() > 0

Comment: @T.N. - My point about about a [mcve] still stands. Whatever circumstances you think are pertinent, a comment is not a replacement for showing a proper example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`push_back` to vector invalidates all previous references/pointers/iterators if a grow operation is triggered and trying to use them after growing is undefined behavior.

In your case the 2nd `list.push_back(line);` is actually triggering a grow, making the previous `reference_wrapper` in `filtered` invalid. While you are trying to access them, you are invoking undefined behavior.

If you want to use in this way you have to ensure that the `vector` has enough space so that a grow operation is not triggered.

Comment: Ohh... so it's better to store the `index` from the `list` instead of the reference then?

Comment: @T.N. index doesn't get invalidated. But not sure whether it will be better without getting more context on what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Well, I just trying to have a source vector and filtered vector so if I modify something in the filtered vector it will also reflect to the source. Maybe I will use `vector<string*>` instead. Thanks!